# How to split an unsigned short in two

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, binary-data

I am trying to parse binary data that I receive in a string. I am not very familiar with bitwise operation.

One of the byte (which I assume is an unsigned short) in my string contains 2 important numbers: the version and a count.
Bits 1 to 4 contain the version, bits 5 to 8 contain the count.

So I have an `unsigned short` containing the data, how do I obtain two unsigned short containing the 2 information I need.

`bit:  1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_`

`con:  VERSION_COUNT___`

Comment: Should it be 'bits 5 to 8 contains the count'?

Comment: unsigned shorts are usually 16 bits, and are at least that many although they can be more as long as they are no bigger than int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift and perform AND operation.

```
int version = value & 0xF;
int count = (value >> 4) & 0xF;
```

or vice versa. Bits as numbers are right to left - 7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0

Comment: There's not a universal way to number bits http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering

Comment: There is in C, and it's inherited in C++. The `>>` and `<<` operators makes it visually clear. `1<<3` is 1 shifted over 3 positions. Since `1<<3 == 8`, we know that bits are counted from the left. Similarly, `128 >> 3 == 16`.

Comment: @MSalters The shift operators do not define how the bits are numbered, and C does not provide any way to refer to a specific bit by number. So, although we know that the binary representation of 1 is 00000001 and 8 is 00001000, nothing in C specifies whether the bit that's set in 00000001 is called "bit 0", "bit 7", or even "bit 8". Bit numbering is generally an issue of documentation, not code: there are not a lot of bit-addressable architectures out there, and (as the wikipedia article says) "Bit numbering is usually transparent to the software".

Comment: @David Gelhar: you're missing the point. Bit numbers represent the value of the corresponding bit. Bit 0 represents the bit with value 2^0, and bit 7 has value 2^7. This holds regardless of the order they appear in a string. Therefore, it's is simple matter of definition that the byte with value 128 has bit 7 set. The only point of argument would be whether that's written (or stored) as 00000001 or 10000000. In C, `128==1<<7`, shifted left. That makes it visually clear what the chosen convention is.

Comment: @MSalters That may be *your* definition of what "bit numbers" mean, but it's by no means universal. For example, in RFCs, the recommended practice is to call the most significant bit of a byte "bit 0".

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned short part1 = data & 0xF; // bits 0..3
unsigned short part2 = (data >> 4) & 0xF; // bits 4..7
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that two pieces of information (version and count) are stored as a pair of two nibbles (4-bit pieces) in a single byte so I think you thought of `unsigned char` type instead of `unsigned short` (in which case you would split it into two bytes). If this is correct, we have two cases of how nibbles are packed:

Case 1: version is higher nibble (bits 4-7) and count is lower nibble (bits 0-3)

```
unsigned char ver = c >> 4;
unsigned char count = (c & 0x0f);
```

Case 2: count is higher nibble (bits 4-7) and version is lower nibble (bits 0-3)

```
unsigned char count = c >> 4;
unsigned char ver = (c & 0x0f);
```

where c is byte containing information and is declared as:

```
unsigned char c;
```

and bit numbering starts at zero for the least significant bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned short version = (unsigned short)(data & 0x0F);

unsigned short count = (unsigned short) (data >> 4);
```